# Dependency of parent project defined with `test` scope is not visible in derived project

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt

Let's say there is project A that has following dependencies.

```
"org.testng" % "testng" % "6.14.3" % "test",
"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.3" % "test",
"org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.14.0" % "test",
"org.hamcrest" % "hamcrest-core" % "1.3" % "test"
```

There is also project B that depends on project A via `sbt.Project.dependsOn(projectA)`.

Tests in project B are not compiled due to missing `org.scalatest.*`.

Is that by design? How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like by default `.dependsOn` uses only `compile` scope. In order to make it work for tests I had to changed to

```
.dependsOn(projectA % "compile->compile;test->test")
```

More information about it [here](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Multi-Project.html#Per-configuration+classpath+dependencies).